# Answer the Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Science Fiction and Fantasy's answer rate is at 95% (as shown [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites)) which may sound high, but that ranks us 45th out of 81 sites. Come on! We can do better than that!

I propose that from **February 1st to February 7th**, we put some focus towards answering the so-far-unanswerable. It's a mission! Right now there are **[133 unanswered questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/unanswered)** on the site, meaning they're either questions with no answer provided **or** the answer provided has yet to be upvoted. Around 35 of these are [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions, which I don't expect to be answered easily. Let's aim for the rest!

**Check these questions out** when you're killing time on the site, in between providing the awesome questions and answers you write every day. Read through the provided answers and **upvote them if you think they're awesome** (they may have slipped past your attention initially or be from before your time). If the answer is not awesome, **would an edit improve it**? Does it need a **whole new answer**? Make those changes! Get those points!

Let's make the site comprehensive and robust with information! Let's do this!

Comment: Too bad I have to wait until tomorrow to start to work on this!

Comment: @DavRob60 No one TOUCHES those questions until I say so!!!

Comment: Iv'e gone through a number of unanswered questions and just could not find the answers for them.  (One that stuck in my head was if/when FDR appeared in Buck Rogers.)  Maybe there are times when we just challenge people more than the other sites?

Comment: I have also spent hours trying to find answers to some of the unanswerables. Some questions we may just need to wait until the right person comes along who can answer them.

Comment: I for one welcome our new Brett Overlords!

Comment: @BrettWhite - off-topic - Brett, why isn't your name followed by the CHAOS character? Is that just you, or the special CHAOS sign was removed from all members?

Comment: @DVK http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110963/165580

Comment: Note that 60% of the unanswered questions have 4 or fewer votes, which is very low for this site.  That might be because they are obscure, but it might also be because they are not very interesting questions and so not worth much effort answering.  Consider down-voting (with comments!) and/or editing the *question*, as well as answering.

Comment: @BrettWhite: Too bad, I just closed 2 of them out;-)

Comment: Those sites with 100% are a bit suspicious.  No question too hard?  Really?

Comment: How about doing one of your great DVD offers here?

Comment: @Wikis That's a thing that could eventually happen. I want to see what can be accomplished first, though, before launching a big contest.

Comment: You mention points to get, is this a promotional event?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Nope. You'll just get the points you earn from answering questions and getting votes.

Comment: That is lame. ;P

Comment: Also, I really really tried to find answers to the unanswered questions I came across, I'm afraid I won't be much help here...

Comment: I knocked two off the list :D