# Fill the empty tag excerpts

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Tag excerpts are very useful. They provide  a brief [“elevator pitch”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) for a tag, explaining the meaning for those unfamiliar with a series. At least as important, excerpts and wikis can also help clarify the usage of tags, particularly those that tend to be used incorrectly, e.g. [frozen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frozen),  [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), or [humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans).

**As of this post, though, nearly 400 tags lack both tag wikis and tag excerpts!** A query (updated only once a week) to show how many can be found [here.](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/445925/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki) I know that somewhere here we have an expert for  every tag, whether they have 2 reputation or 200,000: someone who can provide a well-written, original tag excerpt or tag wiki for a tag that was previously forlorn and undescribed.

There are benefits to editing tag wikis:

- If you have less than 20,000 reputation, as do most people on this site, and you create a tag wiki (which requires approval), **you will get a nice shiny +2 reputation.** What’s more, tag wikis and tag excerpts count as separate posts.
- If you have more than 20,000 reputation, you can edit tag wikis freely. You might also progress toward [any](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/tag-editor) [of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/80/research-assistant) [several](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) [badges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor).

Questions and answers are the lifeblood of this site, but the little things that hang around the periphery are important too! **This month, in the spirit of [Answer the Unanswered Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/answer-the-unanswered-questions), let’s try to provide tag excerpts (and when needed, wikis) for as many of those blank tags as we can.**

Guidelines for writing tag wiki excerpts are [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). And, although it is not mentioned there, a **tag wiki and excerpt should be *original*: no Wikipedia lifting!**

Comment: .....aaaaand now the review queue is filled with crap that people have copied/pasted from wikipedia :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Not yet. :) But perhaps that’s something worth adding to the question.

Comment: @Valorum You could post an answer here with some guidelines on how to write good tag wikis, perhaps? There are already some existing meta posts which could be quoted in such an answer, like [this one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1626/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - There are those with far more experience than I. Personally I think tag wikis are of dubious benefit anyway.

Comment: I don't know about the tag wiki, but having the excerpt hopefully helps people (particularly new users) from choosing the wrong tag when making a new question.

Comment: They're not hard to write.  The hard part is - given the thousands of imaginary worlds that are covered - finding one where you'd actually know what it is.

Comment: Or one that's useful enough to bother with... subtags are way inconsistent.  I wouldn't bother writing an [eye-of-the-world] excerpt when it only has 2 questions and none of the other individual novels in that series have tags (except [a-memory-of-light] w/ 26 q's, which mostly seems to exist for finale questions, and doesn't look used well either)

Comment: @Radhil - If, in the course of filling in the tag excerpts, you come across the tags that *should not be*, you can edit them out, possibly after discussing it with moderators or on meta if uncertain or likely to be controversial.

Comment: @Valorum not so dubious as you proposed. They are useful to clear out when they should be used.

Comment: I notice that several of the tags are character tags (e.g. [tag:beast-boy], [tag:captain-cold], [tag:nicholas-flamel]). Should we write tag wikis for them or just remove them? On the one hand, we have a meta question [about not having them](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/843/13217), but we also have tags like [tag:voldemort] with over 300 questions.

Comment: @Thunderforge - They do exist, and thus deserve wikis. Policy can be hammered out later.

Comment: @Adamant To clarify, should I write a tag wiki for them or edit the questions to remove them? I don't want to waste time writing a tag wiki if they shouldn't exist in the first place and will eventually be deleted.

Comment: @Thunderforge - It is probably better to spend time on work and author tags, in my opinion. There  are more of them, and they are not at risk of vanishing. If you see a character tag that meets no standard of notability (say, one question), it is probably fine to edit it out.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I have removed at least one tag like that but those are pretty specific characters and not likely to be badly used or confused, even if not many will actually use them.  Err on the side of keeping what exists unless its pretty bad, would be my thought.

Comment: I believe that there needs to be better guidance on how to write these things, ideally with officially approved examples. The #2, #3, and #4 tags currently are “harry-potter,” “star-wars” and “star-trek,” and they all seem to violate the rule “Avoid defining the concept behind a tag.” And I don’t understand “Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community.” What is Harry Potter supposed to *mean* to SF&F SE that is different from what he means to the world at large?

Comment: (1) I’m not sure that I understand what you’re saying. Are you saying that all tag wikis that are in place have been approved, and therefore, by definition, they are “officially approved examples”? That’s not quite right. Any user (above some trivial minimum rep, like a few hundred) can suggest edits to tag wikis. Any two users with rep ≥ 5K can approve such a suggestion. Users with rep ≥ 20K can edit tag wikis without peer review. (2) If you think you understand what SF&F tag wikis should look like, please post a feature request asking that the SF&F-specific tag wiki guidance be corrected.

Comment: @PeregrineRook anyone can suggest tag wiki edits. I think.

Comment: @PeregrineRook - Well, to start with, this advice is not really followed. Just look at the tag wiki for [email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) on StackOverflow. It actually defines what email is! So (guidance aside), I don’t think this is much of an issue. But perhaps as important: The *actual* advice is “Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.” Most of our tags *are* highly specialized. Aside from a few common franchises, most people are not going to have any idea what something like [tag:assity-shards] is.

Comment: @Adamant Assity assity ass shards - sounds like someone singing about posterior shrapnel.

Comment: @Randal’Thor - That’s a mistake. It should read [tag:assiti-shards].

Comment: Now that September is over, how about posting a wrap-up answer to this question listing the number of tag wikis/excerpts filled and maybe thanking all those who contributed? (*If* that information is readily available somewhere - I'm not sure whether it is, short of browsing through a month's worth of suggested edits.)

Comment: @Randal’Thor - It’s definitely on my to-do list.